# Jetpack Compose equivalent of layout_weight

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What is the Jetpack Compose equivalent of `layout_weight` in XML?

I need a Modifier which says that a component's height should be, say, 500 DP plus half of the remaining height after all other components have been placed.

You could do that in XML with:

```
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

...with another component also having `layout_weight="1"` so as to share the remaining space equally.

In Compose, we have `Modifier.weight()` but that just tells a component to take a weighted proportion of the available space. No consideration for the size of it *plus* the weighted space.

How can I tell something to be 500px plus half the remaining space in Compose?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the size first and then the weight? The order of modifiers matters, so you could try `Modifier.size(500.dp).weight(1f)` Also, you could play with the `fill` flag in the `weight`, if `true` the element will be forced to occupy the whole width allocated to it. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)

Comment: @WilsonCastiblanco Thanks but that doesn't work. The .weight() overrides the .size(). If you switch it round, the size() overrides the weight(). It's never a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not possible to use height when using weight and vice versa, you can use `BoxWithConstraint` and apply the weight modifier to it and add its maximum height to 500dp and apply it to the desired element like following code:

```kotlin
BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .background(color = Color.Gray)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height((this@BoxWithConstraints.maxHeight / 2) + 100.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(color = Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. So the `BoxWithConstraints` is given a weight, and my element is put inside it. Then the element is given a maximum height - is that right? If so how is that done? There's no `Modifier.maxHeight(xxx)` property to set

Comment: @HughHughTeotl i edited answer for you

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you. That works for if you want to set the Box to a specific height (in your example 100 DP plus a portion of the remainder). Can it work, though, if you want the Box to take its usual height (as defined by its content) plus a proportion of what remains?